# How to export data to pdf in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I don't have grid view as I am working on asp.net MVC.

So can I create Response object which writes data into pdf format

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=data.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "application/.pdf";
```

I use these two lines but I don't know in which format, I should write data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use a pdf library like [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/). just do a google search.
I usually generate my pdf reports on the fly using report [viewer control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) (client-side mode).

Comment: http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/examples.html


here are the good examples + .dll file for com.lowagie.text package.

Answer (score 0):

LOL.

You need to get PDF converter to convert from whichever format you use to PDF. The last I checked there were no fully functional converters for free. Buy it, buddy.